# Refer to a column name alias in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias

I have written down this query in postgres sql with column alias it is working fine:

```
select email as e from users
```

It displays me result under `e` column alias but when I fire `where` condition with `e` then it shows this error:

```
select email as e from users where e = 'jaskaransingh@demo.com'
```

> ERROR:  column "e" does not exist

Why so? How we can use alias in where condition?

Comment: Any updates for a solution ?:)

Answer (score 20):

`where` is evaluated before `select`, so you can't use alias declared in `select` in `where` clause.

Comment: This is correct but makes me sad. Is there a good reason for this? Would be so useful to be able to refer to aliases in the `where` clause.